# Virtual Alloc failing with code 87 - Invalid parameter

Tags: c++, c, qt, winapi

following code is working on some PCs, while on other giving error 87 - invalid parameter, what can be wrong?

```
FileSize = dwDllSize;
buffer = VirtualAlloc ( NULL, FileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE );

if ( !buffer )
{
    QMessageBox::warning(NULL,QString("VirtualAlloc failed!"),QString::number(GetLastError()));
    return -1;
}
```

I'm checking for size 0, and file is not bigger than ~200kb.

Comment: Well, there is only one relevant parameter, and you are not displaying it or logging it?

Comment: You might want to include FizeSize in the warning message to verify if you're assumptions about it are correct.

Comment: You should also double-check the error code; the code as posted isn't reliable in that respect.  You need to retrieve the error code first, stick it in a variable, and only then construct your warning message.